# Numpy C-Api array_equal

Tags: numpy, scipy, python-c-api

I've tried to find function comparing two PyArrayObject - something like [numpy array_equal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html) But I haven't found anything. Do you know function like this?

If not - How to import this numpy array_equal to my C code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code for `array_equal`:

```
def array_equal(a1, a2):
    try:
        a1, a2 = asarray(a1), asarray(a2)
    except:
        return False
    if a1.shape != a2.shape:
        return False
    return bool(asarray(a1 == a2).all())
```

As you can see it is not a `c-api` level function.  After making sure both inputs are arrays, and that shape match it performs a element `==` test, followed by `all`.

This does not work reliably with floats.  It's ok with ints and booleans.

There probably is some sort of equality function in the c-api, but a clone of this probably isn't what you need.

---

```
PyArray_CountNonzero(PyArrayObject* self)
```

might be a good function.  I remember from digging into the code earlier that `PyArray_Nonzero` uses it to determine how big of an array to allocate and return.  You could give it an object that compares the elements of your 2 arrays (in what ever way is appropriate given the `dtype`), and then test for a nonzero count.

Or you could construct your own iterator that bails out as soon as it gets a not-equal pair of elements.  Use `nditer` to get the full array broadcasting power.