# numba slower for numpy.bitwise_and on boolean arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am trying numba in this code snippet

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np
from time import time
db  = np.array(np.random.randint(2, size=(400e3, 4)), dtype=bool)
out = np.zeros((int(400e3), 1))

@jit()
def check_mask(db, out, mask=[1, 0, 1]):
    for idx, line in enumerate(db):
        target, vector = line[0], line[1:]
        if (mask == np.bitwise_and(mask, vector)).all():
            if target == 1:
                out[idx] = 1
    return out

st = time()
res = check_mask(db, out, [1, 0, 1])
print 'with jit: {:.4} sec'.format(time() - st)
```

With numba @jit() decorator this code run slower !

- without jit: 3.16 sec
- with    jit: 3.81 sec

just to help understand better the purpose of this code:

```
db = np.array([           # out value for mask = [1, 0, 1]
    # target,  vector     #
      [1,      1, 0, 1],  # 1
      [0,      1, 1, 1],  # 0 (fit to mask but target == 0)
      [0,      0, 1, 0],  # 0
      [1,      1, 0, 1],  # 1
      [0,      1, 1, 0],  # 0
      [1,      0, 0, 0],  # 0
      ])
```

Comment: Look at the `array_equal` code, as shown in my recent answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/34486522/901925.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj I've just updated the snippet to take into account your comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numba has two compilation modes for `jit`: nopython mode and object mode. Nopython mode (the default) supports only a limited set of Python and Numpy features, refer to [the docs for your version](http://numba.pydata.org/doc.html). If the jitted function contains unsupported code, Numba has to fall back to object mode, which is much, much slower.

I'm not sure if objcet mode is supposed to give a speedup compared to pure Python, but you'll always want to use nopython mode anyway. To make sure nopython mode is used, specify `nopython=True` and stick to very basic code (rule of thumb: write out all the loops and only use scalars and Numpy arrays):

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def check_mask_2(db, out, mask=np.array([1, 0, 1])):
    for idx in range(db.shape[0]):
        if db[idx,0] != 1:
            continue
        check = 1
        for j in range(db.shape[1]):
            if mask[j] and not db[idx,j+1]:
                check = 0
                break
        out[idx] = check
    return out
```

Writing out the inner loop explicitly also has the advantage that we can break out of it as soon as the condition fails.

Timings:

```
%time _ = check_mask(db, out, np.array([1, 0, 1]))
# Wall time: 1.91 s
%time _ = check_mask_2(db, out, np.array([1, 0, 1]))
# Wall time: 310 ms  # slow because of compilation
%time _ = check_mask_2(db, out, np.array([1, 0, 1]))
# Wall time: 3 ms
```

BTW, the function is also easily vectorized with Numpy, which gives a decent speed:

```
def check_mask_vectorized(db, mask=[1, 0, 1]):
    check = (db[:,1:] == mask).all(axis=1)
    out = (db[:,0] == 1) & check
    return out

%time _ = check_mask_vectorized(db, [1, 0, 1])
# Wall time: 14 ms
```

Comment: Thanks, using your advices on a more complicate but similar problem I did not succeed to speed up with numba: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34544210/3313834

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can try [Pythran](http://pythran.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
(disclaimer: I am a developer of Pythran).

With a single annotation, it compiles the following code

```
#pythran export check_mask(bool[][], bool[])

import numpy as np
def check_mask(db, out, mask=[1, 0, 1]):
    for idx, line in enumerate(db):
        target, vector = line[0], line[1:]
        if (mask == np.bitwise_and(mask, vector)).all():
            if target == 1:
                out[idx] = 1
    return out
```

with a call to `pythran check_call.py`.

And according to `timeit`, the resulting native module runs pretty fast:

```
python -m timeit -s 'n=1e4; import numpy as np; db  = np.array(np.random.randint(2, size=(n, 4)), dtype=bool); out = np.zeros(int(n), dtype=bool); from eq import check_mask' 'check_mask(db, out)'
```

tells me the CPython version runs in `136ms` while the Pythran-compiled version runs in `450us`.

Comment: I reach to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/35240168/3313834 doing it with pythran. BTW pythran deserve a tag on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend removing the numpy call to array_equal from the inner loop. numba isn't necessarily smart enough to turn this into a piece of inlined C; and should it fail to replace this call, the dominant cost of your function remains comparable, which would explain your result.

While numba can reason about a fair number of numpy constructs, it is only C-style code acting on numpy arrays which one may rely on being accelerated.

Comment: yes, that's why I've removed the array_equal, replaced by np.bitwise_and(mask, vector)

Comment: I am not sure this is a significant difference to numba. You would probably need to manually perform the loop over all components of the mask in order to avoid python calls in the inner loop