# Pythran export dict with tuples as key

Tags: python, dictionary, pythran

I try to use [Pythran](http://pythran.readthedocs.io) in a function that needs an `int` array and for the second arg a `dict` with tuples of `ints` as keys and an `int` as value:

```
myarray = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1],
                    [1, 2], [2, 2], [1, 3]])

dict_with_tuples_key = {(0, 1): 1, (3, 7): 1}
```

What is the correct way to inform *Pythran* about the `dict` ?:

```
#pythran export update_dict((int, int):int dict, int[][])
def update_dict(dict_with_tuples_key, myarray):
    # do something with dict_with_tuples_key and myarray
    # return and updated dict_with_tuples_key
    return dict_with_tuples_key
```

With **(int, int):int dict** I get this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 526, in findsource
  file = getfile(object)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 403, in getfile
  raise TypeError('{!r} is a built-in module'.format(object))
TypeError: <module 'sys' (built-in)> is a built-in module
```

Comment: which version of pythran are you using? Ifail to repoduce your issue with the master (b44c9a38a0894bf89872482a10abee2a61316303) version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your backtrace, it seems you're importing `sys`. In that kind of situation, pythran tries to get the source of the import module to compile it. As `sys` is a built-in module, it fails.

Comment: Ok I get it, I was running pythran on a code.py file with a lot of other functions; I thought that only the one with  `# pythran export ...` comments will be affected by pythran. All work as a charm if I create a dedicated ccompile.py with only the functions I want to give to pythran. The acceleration is amazing !